# Angular cannot resolve ChartJSProvider dependancy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

Trying to override the default ChartJS Series colors but getting an error that Angular cannot resolve the ChartJSProvider dependency. Is this not included in the chart.js module? They don't instruct any other dependencies on the angularjs chart site. The below is no particular order.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module webApp due to: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ChartJSProvider http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=ChartJSProvider

var app = angular.module('webApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ui.bootstrap', 'md-steppers', 'ngMessages', 'remoteValidation', 'chart.js', 'ngTable']);

app.config(['ChartJSProvider', function(ChartJSProvider){
  ChartJSProvider.setOptions({global: {colors:["#2ecc71", "#3498db", "#f1c40f", "#e74c3c"]}});
}]);

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/angular.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/angular-messages.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/md-steppers.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/webapp.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/ngRoute.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/ui-bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/ngRemoteValidate.min.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/shared/oneg.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/shared/style.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/md-steppers.min.css') }}"/>

<link rel="stylesheet"; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>

<!-- Above are bootstrap imports, below are custom imports -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/control_panel.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/deployment_status.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/new_deployment.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/deployment_tasks.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom.css') }}"/>

<!-- Angular Materials v.1.1.0 (and dependencies) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/angular-material.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/material/angular-animate.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/material/angular-aria.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/material/angular-material.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Angular-Chart.js v.1.1.1 and Chart.js v.2.6.0 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/shared/angular-chart.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I think this question is incomplete without showing what scripts you are using on your page. Like it would be great if you list the script tags. Are you using an ng wrapper around chartjs library ?

Comment: @82Tuskers editted with script tags. i omitted cause was confident they were fine. unsure on what you specifically mean around an ng-wrapper around chart.js library. 

i am using the angular charts implementation of chart.js http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

you'll see this config described on the top of the page

Comment: Okay so ng-charts is an ng wrapper over chartjs. Anyway, I think you should call the ChartJSProvider after inclusion of angular-chart.min.js. The provider gets defined in that file (I strongly think).